# MPMediaickerController memory leak identified by Leaks instrument

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is code from Apple's Addmusic example.

```
MPMediaPickerController *picker =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

picker.delegate                        = self;
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems    = YES;
picker.prompt                        = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");

// The media item picker uses the default UI style, so it needs a default-style
//        status bar to match it visually
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated: YES];

[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
[picker release];
```

I'm using this code in my app and the Leaks instrument highlights a leak on the line:

```
[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
```

I think that this is because this line retains a reference to picker which cannot be subsequently released.

Is there any way around this or is Leaks incorrectly identifying a leak?

Comment: have you found the solution to this issue?
Even for "AddMusic" MPMediaPickerController example from Apple, the Instruments shows 100kB growth in memory usage every time after simple opening the picker and then canceling it with done button.

Answer (score 0):

It can be released by a call to `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: So does that mean that Instruments has incorrectly identified a leak because I do dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: later in the code?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm wondering why the [picker release] line is there though, why would the calling code be releasing it if it hasn't retained it?

Comment: picker is retained with the [MPMediaPickerController alloc] line so it has to be released with [picker release]

Comment: yep gotcha, just ignore me :)